# error: No resource identifier found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ctc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.hulist.asm.person"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.hulist.asm.person.ImageMap
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/person"
        ctc:map="person_map" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

and on line 8 (`<com.hulist.asm.person.ImageMap`) there is an error saying

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'map' in package 'com.hulist.asm.person'

I've been trying to fix this for a few days now, what am I dong wrong?

Comment: Not enough context.. How is `map` defined? Is `com.hulist.asm.person` your current package name?

Comment: @K-ballo `com.hulist.asm.person` is the package where `ImageMap` class is. and for the `map` - I thought it shouldn't be defined anywhere else before. `@+id/map` adds this identifier for the first time right..?

Comment: So what is the current package name? And yes, but the error is not about `@+id/map` its about `ctc:map`

Comment: @K-ballo oh, so that's what it's about! And by current package name you mean the root package name? it's `com.hulist.asm`.

Comment: I mean the package name as specified in the manifest of the project you are currently working on. That's what the `ctc` namespace declaration should have.

Comment: @K-ballo thank you, I learned yet another thing today :) as it actually is working with package name from manifest! post this as answer and I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your current package name is `com.hulist.asm`, then that is what the `ctc` namespace declaration should have instead of

```
xmlns:ctc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.hulist.asm.person"
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you are referring to the same scenario which has been addressed in [bug 9656](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9656).
Take a look at that and if it is the same, check whether you are using an older version of sdk tools.

Comment: I don't think this is a library project, but even then don't `auto` namespaces fix that?